# Install an R package on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install this package from the Comprehensive R Archive Network, but I cannot see how to do it. What steps are involved in installing an R package?

Comment: Yes, I try to do : sudo apt-get install imputation  but i get this message "E: Impossible de trouver le paquet imputation
"

Answer (score 0):

It seems the imputation package was discontinued. You can download it from the ppa below by typing at the terminal:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~tbooth/+archive/ubuntu/ppa1/+build/4514765/+files/r-bioc-impute_1.34.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

To install it, type

```
sudo dpkg -i r-bioc-impute_1.34.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (64-bit) with the core R package installed.